# from module import * using full path in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

How do I write a code equivalent to

```
from mymodule import *
```

for a module in a given full path?

My question is similar to this question: [How do I import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-do-i-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)
, except I want to "import * "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to add your full path to `sys.path`:

```
import sys

sys.path.append('<path_to_folder_with_your_module>')

from mymodule import *
```